# Error1 upload failure vscode: "ser_open(): can't open device ".\COM11""

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino

I'm trying to upload my code to an arduino leonardo using VSCode + Platformio IDE.

As I connect the mC its been detected in port COM 10. tring to upload it tries to force the port for the upload but then it rejected and the shown faillure appears on another port ( COM 11 here for the case). the weird thing is that, on some other Laptops, the upload is running normally and the mC is working. I tried in other ports on my laptop and other devices and other mCs to check if the usb is working well and its the case.

I have the following error as output :

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device ".\COM11": The specified file can not be found.
> avrdude done. Thank you.
> *** [upload] Error 1
> == [FAILED] Took 23.53

I'll be very greatful if someone can help.